# Probability (continuity) problem with limits

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits

> "In a series of games, the winning number of the $n$th game is selected at random from the set $\{1,2,3, ... , (n+2) \}$. Bob bets on $1$ in each game. He will quit as soon as he wins.
>
> Show that the probability Bob will play forever is zero.
>
> Hint: Define a decreasing sequence of events which all occur if Bob plays forever."

I am unable to get $0$:

Let $E_n$ : Bob loses the $n$th game and {$ E_i$} be the decreasing sequence.

$$P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=0}^\infty E_i\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(E_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1{n+2}\right)=1$$

Can somebody point out my mistake please?

Comment: Define $E_n$ to be the event that Bob loses in all first $n$ games.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that he loses the first game is: $$1-\frac{1}{1+2} = \frac23$$

The probability that he loses the second game is $$1-\frac{1}{2+2} = \frac34$$

Notice the pattern here as we keep continuing in the games.

The probability that he loses any game is independent of another game's outcome.

So we have that the probability he loses all the games up to and including the $n$th is $$\frac{2}{3} *\frac34 * \frac45 * \dots*\frac{n}{n+1}*\frac{n+1}{n+2} = \frac{2}{n+2}$$
Now look at the limit of this as $n$ goes to $\infty$

---

As for your mistake, all you did was look at the probability that he loses the $n$th game specifically as $n$ went to $\infty$, which logically should come out to $1$. As we keep adding more possible winning numbers, the chances that he loses any individual game should approach $1$ as there would be infinitely more other numbers for the winning number to be, making it nearly impossible for him to win.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: If this answer helped you feel free to accept it / upvote it, and you are welcome